# error on running "rails db:seed" after installing ActiveAdmin gem and running "rails g active_admin:install" and "rails db:migrate"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

this the first time I use ActiveAdmin gem, I have a sample application just consists of User table (it's just a signup login registration system til now), to install the ActiveAdmin gem first I added it to my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.5.1"

    gem 'rails',        '5.1.4'
    gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.3'
    gem 'devise', '~> 4.4', '>= 4.4.3'
    gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
    gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.12'
    gem 'faker',          '1.7.3'
    gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
    gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
    gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
    gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
    gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
    gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'
    gem 'carrierwave', '~> 0.11.2'

    group :development, :test do
      gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
      gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
    end

    group :development do
      gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
      gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
      gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
      gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
    end

    group :test do
      gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
      gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
      gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
      gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
      gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
    end

    group :production do
      gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
    end

    # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
    gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

then I ran

```
rails g active_admin:install
```

to install the active admin, then I ran to migrate the changes

```
rails db:migrate
```

now I got error when running

```
rails db:seed
```

the error is

```
rails aborted!
SyntaxError: /home/elta3lab/Rails/amazon/db/seeds.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
...ord') if Rails.env.development?
...                               ^
/home/elta3lab/Rails/amazon/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/elta3lab/Rails/amazon/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/elta3lab/Rails/amazon/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

knowing that this is the content of my db/seeds.rb file

```
User.create!(name:  "Ahmed Mohamed Fouad",
             email: "ahmedfouad@gmail.com",
             password:              "12345678",
             password_confirmation: "12345678",
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

User.create!(name:  "Ahmed Fouad",
             email: "elta3lab@gmail.com",
             password:              "12345678",
             password_confirmation: "12345678",
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name:  name,
               email: email,
               password:              password,
               password_confirmation: password,
               activated: true,
               activated_at: Time.zone.now)
endAdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') if Rails.env.development?
```

I feel that it's a very simple problem, but I searched too long and got nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it looks like just an imbalanced syntax around the last `end`,

```
User.create!(name:  "Ahmed Mohamed Fouad",
             email: "ahmedfouad@gmail.com",
             password:              "12345678",
             password_confirmation: "12345678",
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

User.create!(name:  "Ahmed Fouad",
             email: "elta3lab@gmail.com",
             password:              "12345678",
             password_confirmation: "12345678",
             activated: true,
             activated_at: Time.zone.now)

99.times do |n|
  name  = Faker::Name.name
  email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
  password = "password"
  User.create!(name:  name,
               email: email,
               password:              password,
               password_confirmation: password,
               activated: true,
               activated_at: Time.zone.now)
end
AdminUser.create!(email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password') if Rails.env.development?
```

Comment: glad to be of help :)